# Chrome gives different results in karma than alone

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, typescript, karma-runner

I have a small app that I have been working on the UI with the client.  I am using TypeScript and Angular write the client code.  I created a bar bones controller to deliver hard-coded data to the UI for layout purposes and it has been working fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Now that I am ready to start adding business logic I want to implement testing, so I installed karma (which has been challenging to say the least).  When I run the code with karma using the Chrome browser I get a "function is undefined" error on a function exported from a TypeScript module that still works just fine when I use Chrome outside of karma (in WebStorm). The property is there, but the defined function is not.

[image]

The js generated code seems classic and conventional to me.

[image]

Can someone tell me why the code behaves differently under karma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I run the code with karma using the Chrome browser I get a "function is undefined" error on a function exported from a TypeScript module that still works just fine when I use Chrome outside of karma (in WebStorm). The property is there, but the defined function is not

Mainly just ensure correct order of file (script) loading.